# specific bug in code when iterating using indexOf() Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have been going through the FreeCodeCamp's Bonfire algorithm challenges, and with this particular challenge we are given two parameters and asked to use indexOf() to match up all of the characters from the second parameter's string with the first one, and if the second parameter contains a letter that is not present in the first parameter the function should return false.

With the function I have written here, I pass all of the test parameters that they use except for when they pass:

```
    mutation("hello", "hey");
```

Even when I try running the function in other places, calling this function with the parameters above still returns true where it should be returning false.

```
function mutation(arr) {

  var arr0 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var arr1 = arr[1].toLowerCase().split(''); //breaks characters into an array

  for (var i = 0, length = arr1.length; i < length; i++) {

    var check = arr0.indexOf(arr1[i]); // each element in arr1 is checked
    if (check === -1) {                // against arr0
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
  }
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]); //returns true, but I can't find out know why
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this out of the loop:

```
return true;
```

so after the brace that follows it.

This is because you can only know whether the result is true when you have checked all the characters. As you have it now the for-loop actually never loops, it always returns on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function mutation(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++){
    if (arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[1][i].toLowerCase()) == -1)
      return false;
    }
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how does it work.